# Is there an alternative IDE to develop android applications other then Eclipse?

Tags: android, ide

I'm developing android applications in Eclipse IDE. Now, i want to know if any other IDE available for developing android applications. Anyone knows means tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715697/what-is-the-best-ide-to-develop-android-apps-in

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because question about software recommendations should be asked at: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android plugin can be installed in NetBeans as well. This is an alternate IDE (but do remember that Android is not officially supported by NetBeans, so some difficulties may occur while installing the plugin).

Intellij comes with Android plugin pre installed. Moto Dev Studio for Android also has Android support.

[See this](http://androidworkz.com/android-resources/)

Answer (score 2):

You also have MotoDev Studio (based on eclipse) from Motorola-> [link](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/)

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/10/intellij-idea-10-free-ide-for-android-development/

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA has a built in plug in for android development you can use. You can give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html), just this.
It's very fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) for developing android application. Because, it'll support both  `Android` and `Iphone` And, its having `JavaScript` language to develop the applications.