# Start developing for Android?

Tags: android

I've been wanting to develop applications for Android for a while now.
I download the ADT Plugin for Eclipse from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html, and started to develop applications using Eclipse. However, even the simplest Hello World application seems to take a few minutes to run.

I was wondering if there are better environments for Android Development.
Is it possible to develop application using NetBeans or other Java compilers?
Are there faster development tools than the ADT Plugin for Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative IDE to develop android applications other then Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387382/is-there-an-alternative-ide-to-develop-android-applications-other-then-eclipse)

Comment: Running the emulator for the first time is quite pain indeed. However, if you don't shut it down, then new/modified applications are installed and run in several seconds.

Comment: Also make sure to check *"Snapshots: Enabled"* from the avd config, as well as *"Start from snapshot"* and *"save to snapshot"* when launching the avd. This saves and restores the emulator state to and from disk, resulting in a way faster start after it has been run for the first time (the emulator doesnt respond for a few secs due to writing to the disk when closing though - but well worth the tradeoff).

Answer (score 1):

If the application takes a long time to run, check one of two things:

Does your PC meets the requirements of eclipse.

If the application is taking a few minutes to run, it is quite possible that you may be closing the emulator after every debugging. This is unnecessary as the debugger is always listening for eclipse to run.

I do not know if these are possibilities, but I want your Android programming experience to be a good one. Troubleshooting is never useless :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it runs slow, but I don't think switching IDEs is going to make it any faster. Such is the nature of Java and other interpreted languages. A faster machine is all that helps. I have noticed things move better once loaded the first time, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is taking a few minutes, but developing with an actual device can hugely lower the waiting time as the emulator is really slow (uploading your app, installing, running and using it). 
If you want to use the emulator be sure to not close the emulator window all the time as it will have to boot Android the next time you run your app.

I don't think that you will be more happy with another IDE or something like that, as it will only cause more work and more problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with emulator - do not shut it down. First start is painful, but then it's faster.