# Alternate Android Development Environments

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Currently I am using Eclipse IDE with ADT plugin for my Android application development. Is there any other development tools for this purpose on Windows Environment. I am specially interested in any such tool which allows the UI preparation with drag and drop of components (like drag and drop buttons, textboxes etc).

And I'm not interested in HTML5, CSS based IDEs like Titanium Studio or PhoneGap like frameworks. Looking for a tool which would allow me to develop in native Java but with rich UI design features. Additional Eclipse plugin which provides this type of UI preparation would also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android was built with keeping Eclipse (for Development) in mind.
And its officially supported by Android.

I will recommend you if you are coming to Android as fresh, Use Eclipse and understand.
As it support Drag and Drop of control (from XML, I wonder if you are ignorant of that.)

and if you are coming with another IDE, options are available

[A use full discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1715697/593709)

Comment: Yes I am new to Android development and I didn't knew Eclipse had capability to design the mobile app UI with drag and drop of controls. Can you point me to a good tutorial for this? Thanks.

Comment: @BathiyaPriyadarshana:yea! for sure. Here you go to the official sample of [Android Hello World with XML UI layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#upgrading)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

1. IntelliJ IDEA
2. Netbeans
3. Eclipse

as per your choice.... An official free IDE for IntelliJ android dev! 
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/10/intellij-idea-10-free-ide-for-android-development/

But Switching from Eclipse is not that good idea either.. good to learn Eclipse which is very good for android as per me.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I also prefer Eclipse but the problem I am facing is designing the UI. Any plugins that you know of which comes for Eclipse specifically to design the UI of the mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we open xml files ,it left hand side Graphical Layout is Available using widgets we can drag and drop like buttons,text boxes,Image button including Image buttons and drag some special fields like phone numer password fields

another alternate option is

There is a Droiddraw software is available for designing UI ,its specially for android UI