# What is the best ide for creating Android Tablet apps?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best IDE to develop Android apps in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715697/what-is-the-best-ide-to-develop-android-apps-in)

I need to create a app in android that connects my client to it's desktop databases.

He uses Xoom tablet and it's big screen should be entirelly used to show informations about his customers and his daily attending agenda.

What is the best IDE for creating this app visually?

*I don't want to make it all by notepad!*

Comment: Someone in my class told me that it doesn't have a tablet screen layout editor. :(

Comment: Eclipse, combined with the ADT plugin (the Android Developer Tools) and the Android SDKs, does have a layout designer. It's not very good, but it's better than nothing and it has improved a little bit recently. In short, do not listen to your classmate. If you want to program in Java on Android, and if you're a beginner, Eclipse is your best option right now.

Comment: I use `MOTODEV Studio for Android` and it's fine. It's a Eclipse version boosted by Motorola. It should have what you need because it's the same manufacturer of Xoom. @StephanBranczyk Tell me please, if you're not a beginner, what is the best ide?

Comment: I took a look just now in the motodev's website. I think this suits my needs. Thank you all!

Comment: @EASI even professionals use eclipse, [ItelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html) is the second popular alternative. There are tons of websites / blogposts comparing them just google or try them both yourself

Comment: Yes, MotoDev is probably even better for beginners, but since it's a version behind the official ADT on Eclipse, it may not have the most recent improvements to the layout designer -- but it still should be fine.

Comment: Well, they're more in sync with the motorola devices needs. It has to versions: one for Android 4 and one for the rest, and a community for it's own. She should look if it has the config she needs. Meanwhile I shaw test this ItelliJ... :)