# How to access ant in Android Command Line?

Tags: java, android, ant

I am new to Android programming and since I find Eclipse environment uncomfortable as it generates plenty of unneccessary files, I decided to make everything "by hand".

I am now trying to compile the first app using the command line. According to the Android developers manual, I have to "navigate to the root directory of my app and run ant", but when attempt to do so, it doesn't run the ant tools because... well, there is no ant executable file in my app root directory?

The **ant** directory is located in build-tools, but no ant executable is there, either, so naturally the cmd cannot run it. When is the ant actually, then, and how can it be run?

Thank you for response in advance

Comment: Come back to Eclipse or go with Android Studio

Comment: Yeah, I will probably take your advice as I seem to be too stupid for finding the ant exec file. :D

Comment: There can not be any ant in there anyway for ant is a product from Apache and not from Google. And they are using gradle for building not ant

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use Eclipse, try to check this  [What is the best IDE to develop Android apps in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715697/what-is-the-best-ide-to-develop-android-apps-in)

If you really want to compile with command line be sure that Environmental Variables are set up for ANT.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, Ant is not included in the basic SDK files and has to be installed separately. Thank you.

Comment: Quote from [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) : "If you don't have Ant, you can obtain it from the Apache Ant home page. Install it and make sure it is in your executable PATH. Before calling Ant, you need to declare the JAVA_HOME environment variable to specify the path to where the JDK is installed." Hope it helps